# What is the Hebrew term for the drawing of the hands inward during lighting of Shabbos candles?

Tags: shabbat, words, hebrew, candle-lighting

Someone elsewhere asked what is the **Hebrew term** for the drawing of the hands inward during lighting of Shabbos candle.

For example, [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/87131/jewish/Shabbat-Candles-Instructions.htm) describes the custom,

> Extend your hands over the candles, draw them inwards three times in a circular motion, and then cover your eyes.

In addition, perhaps there is no actual term. But, if one can provide an actual Hebrew text describing the practice (nothing too modern), perhaps I can see how the author describes it in Hebrew.

Note: After some research, it seems to me that this tradition must have originated as a result of the Shabbos song, [לכה דודי](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekhah_Dodi), composed by Rabbi Shlomo ha-Levi Alkabetz. In it, we find the lyric פני שבת נקבלה, "Let us welcome the presence of Shabbos."

So, is this motion with the hands basically understood to represent קבלת [פני] שבת?

Comment: I don't think I've heard a concise term for that in any language (though I don't have much exposure to Yiddish so they may have one).  What non-Hebrew terms have you heard for this?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: None really. Just English verb like "draw(ing)."

Comment: טעמי המנהגים‎ 261 calls it "שמשימין היד לפני הנר אחר הדלקה בע״ש ומברכין ואח״כ מסלקין היד", but I guess that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: The better question is why circle three times

Comment: @sam maybe it is from kabbalah, once for each veil of light before Keter.

Comment: @msh210 That's not the same minhag.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's why I guessed what I guessed.

Comment: לכסות את עיניהן

Comment: Concealing or covering the eyes is just one part of the custom.